# Comparing string with a database object django

Tags: database, django, templates, object, comparison

Env: Python 2.7.3 || Django 1.4.1

I am trying to limit web page menu options based on the Role of the logged in user. I have created a UserProfile class in the models and linked it to User as descibed in the docs (works perfectly in Django Admin, when adding users). For example, normal users will only have "home" and "mytasks" while admin users will also have "domain tasks" in addition.

Here is code in the base.html template:

```
{% if user.get_profile.role == "Admin" %}
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="{% url home %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url mytasks %}">My Tasks</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url domaintasks %}">Domain Tasks</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Above is checked when rendering the navigation bar for the whole site.

I think the issue is in comparing a string with a database object (printed below) but haven't been able to find out how to get the comparison to work.

```
>>> b = Role.objects.all()
>>> print b
[<Role: Admin>, <Role: User>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it.

- Check against the appropriate attribute of `Role`, instead of the object as you doing. So if you have `name` attribute in `Role`, you can check as

`{% if user.get_profile.role.name == "Admin" %}`

- Another way if you can modify code of `Role` model is to implement a method in `Role` model to check if role is admin and use it in template.

`{% if user.get_profile.role.is_admin %}`

Comment: Thought I wasn't far, inside my head I had symlinked Role object to an attribute of the role... added the atrribute and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

The right way to solve your problem would be to create groups for each type of user using  you can django admin assign these groups on user sign up, you can even write a script for existing users, and then use the in_group template filter to check if the user has the required privileges.

but going with your approach, is role an attribute or a function in userprofile class which returns a string? if it is then i think your code should work.
but if role is a foriegn key object to another model then you should compare using something like:-

```
user.get_profile.role.attribute_in_the_other_model
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I did not want to question my approach yet as I wanted to have a clear question and my first iteration working. I was thinking of roles initially, will have a closer look at it on next cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to call the string representation methods of the Role model

```
{% if user.get_profile.role.__str__ == "Admin" %}
```

or

```
{% if user.get_profile.role.__unicode__ == "Admin" %}
```